# Comment « pourvoir » glisse-t-il sémantiquement pour signifier « faire appel au tribunal » ?

Tags: étymologie

Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « orner, douer » (les acceptions plus coutumières) avec #7 sur [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pourvoir#Verbe)?

> 7. *(Pronominal)* *(Droit)* [Intenter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/intenter) une [action](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/action) [devant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/devant) un [juge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/juge), [recourir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/recourir) à un [tribunal](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tribunal), à une [autorité](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/autorit%C3%A9) ; [faire appel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_appel).

Comment: Je vais oser une explication très basique: "se pourvoir" a été inscrit dans la constitution et/ou dans la loi, donc ce terme a été conservé au fil du temps alors qu'on l'a oublié dans le language courant.

Answer (score 1):

*<sup>Deux définitions du petit Robert :</sup>*

> — *Sémantique* : étude du langage considéré du point de vue du sens.
>
> — *Se pourvoir* : Faire en sorte de posséder, (d’avoir une chose nécessaire).

*<sup>Appliquées à la Justice :</sup>*

Pour se procurer une décision de Justice, n’est-il pas nécessaire de *faire en sorte d’obtenir* (pour en être le "propriétaire") un jugement favorable ? On se *prémunit* contre l’adversité et on *prévoit* d’avoir gain de cause.

On *se pourvoie* à tous les étages de la hiérarchie procédurale, en première instance, en appel, en cassation, devant la Cour européenne … devant l’instance du tribunal qui juge son cas. — Le ‘glissement’ de la question n’est qu’un effet d’optique dû à la procédure, une facilité d’usage qui n’induit pas de sens différent.

Le sens usuel apparaît dans la musique des mots, celle induite par l’oreille : pour *se pourvoir* (on dépose *soi-même* une plainte *pour-voir* l’issue du procès), il faut *pré-voir* les arguments adverses, pour *se pré-munir* de leurs attaques.

Le sens premier, *"faire en sorte de posséder"* a été utilisé et adapté au langage judiciaire pour manifester toute volonté de  saisir la Justice afin d’obtenir gain de cause … ce qui entraînera par la suite un paragraphe de plus dans les dictionnaires pour marquer l’évolution différente du mot au fil du temps.

Comment: Merci. +1. J'ai alloué la prime à l'autre répondeur avec moins de réputation, mais je préfère votre réponse.

Answer (score 1):

*Orner/douer* n'est pas le sens le plus courant du verbe pourvoir : *suppléer à ce qui manque* (sens 1) l'est. C'est attesté en 1680 pour *faire appel*. Les trois types d'emploi de pourvoir sont selon le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (DHLF), sup. A. Rey, Robert, 2011 :

1- *voir à l'avance*
 2- *procurer* quelque chose à quelqu'un, et avec *à*, *parer/subvenir à*
 3- pronominal avec *de* pour *s'approvisionner* .

Ensuite suivent les extensions de sens... « pourvoir quelqu'un », le *mettre en possession d'un avantage*, et « pourvoir quelque chose », *munir* etc. Puis en construction indirecte on a *pourvoir à*, un emploi vieilli du 14<sup>e</sup>, puis *pourvoir aux besoins de quelqu'un* (1668), usuel. (DHLF)

Puis on indique que « *se pourvoir* se spécialise en droit pour "recourir à une juridiction supérieure" (1680). » (DHLF). On passerait de l'idée de *s'approvisionner* à celle de *recourir à*, les deux impliquant de recourir à un tiers ? Je ne peux dire précisément pourquoi ce « glissement » s'effectue le cas échéant. Soit dit en passant au Canada l'emploi contemporain du [substantif](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=9_Xy2gVAQ5z8.html#zz9_Xy2gVAQ5z8_1) est réservé à un contexte particulier.

Comment: J'ai recopié mon commentaire pour ajouter à la réflexion davantage que pour répondre définitivement, à l'évidence.